# How i make json.loads turn str into int

Tags: python, json

I need '-40' to be -40 on the output, how i can do this?

```
In [2]: foo
Out[2]: '{\n\t"rssiIntentRange":"-40"\n}'

In [3]: import json

In [4]: json.loads(foo)
Out[4]: {u'rssiIntentRange': u'-40'}
```

Im searching for something clean and generic. Doing treatments after the json.loads is what im already doing and its very dirty because of all types of data and indexes. If json.loads is not the best option im open to other approaches as well that treats JSON

Comment: Did you try using object_hook of JSONDecoder? You can also pass custom decoder to json.load or json.loads. See: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder

Comment: Maybe you should fix the application that's creating the JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to influence what happens when you call `json.loads()`, you need to write an object hook:

```
import json


def int_please_object_hook(obj):
    """If a value in obj is a string, try to convert it to an int"""
    rv = {}
    for k, v in obj.items():
        if isinstance(v, basestring):
            try:
                rv[k] = int(v)
            except ValueError:
                rv[k] = v
        else:
            rv[k] = v
    return rv


j = '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "10", "key3": "-10"}'

print(json.loads(j))
# {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': '10', 'key3': '-10'}

print(json.loads(j, object_hook=int_please_object_hook))
# {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 10, 'key3': -10}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to convert the `-40` string to int after loading the json.

Example -

```
>>> foo = '{\n\t"rssiIntentRange":"-40"\n}'
>>> import json
>>> d = json.loads(foo)
>>> d['rssiIntentRange'] = int(d['rssiIntentRange'])
>>> d
{'rssiIntentRange': -40}
```

For changing all such values inside the loaded dictionary, you can do -

```
d = json.loads(foo)
for k,v in d.items():
    try:
        d[k] = int(v)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        pass
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> foo = '{\n\t"rssiIntentRange":"-40",\n\t"blah":"abcd",\n\t"anothernumber":"-10"\n}'
>>> d = json.loads(foo)
>>> for k,v in d.items():
...     try:
...         d[k] = int(v)
...     except (ValueError, TypeError):
...         pass
...
>>> d
{'blah': 'abcd', 'anothernumber': -10, 'rssiIntentRange': -40}
```

Comment: yeah, im already doing that. The thing though is that this approach is very dirty and not general at all. At the end of the day its a lot of treatments that i have to do because the function treats all sorts of data. Im searching for an approach with something more clean and general.

Comment: I do not think `json.loads()` would have any inbuilt support for this (or any such method/class in json module for that matter) , since your json has them as strings. Anyway maybe someone else has some better ideas

Comment: in your code the exceptions are ValueError but there are all others that ends up happening and stuff. Specifying index is a bad approach because i have to list all the other values that has the same behaviour as well.

Comment: humm, do you know another approach other tha json.loads?

Comment: What other error can happen when doing `int()` ? And specifying index is wrong why? Its not index actually, its the key, and we need to use key to set the value back in the dictionary.

Comment: An excample is if a dict is sent, it throws TypeError.

Comment: Ok added that as well, and sorry I do not know about any other library other than json for this. And even if there were such libraries, they may not have the functionality you desire, mainly because its rarely every needed to change the type of value returned by json . Example if json intended to send integer, json would look like - `'{\n\t"rssiIntentRange":-40\n}'` . In this json, `json.loads()` would correctly parse -40 as int, not string.

Comment: yeah, true. Thks anyway